# Mule - How to send SOAP Web Service Request?

Tags: web, service, mule

Hi i am doing simple POC in mule.

I have a web service and i want to make it's Client.

It is SOAP web service and i want to send request to it but i am not getting wayout. Please give me some idea.

**Following is code:**

MULE:

```
<cxf:configuration name="CXF_Configuration" enableMuleSoapHeaders="true" initializeStaticBusInstance="true" doc:name="CXF Configuration"/>

<flow name="prjvm1" doc:name="prjvm1">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:5678/httpHello" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
    </http:inbound-endpoint>

    <!-- This logger is just set to show the message accepted from the request -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="VimService"    
                      wsdlLocation="file:/C:/Users/gugla/MuleStudio/workspace/prjvm/bin/service/vService.wsdl" 
                      operation="retrieveServiceContent"  
                      clientClass="com.esxclient.VService" 
                      port="VimPort">
        <cxf:jaxb-databinding/>
    </cxf:jaxws-client>
    <outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/gep-sped/servicos/ServicoDeCadastroEAgendamento" 
                        doc:name="Generic" 
                        exchange-pattern="request-response"/>
    <echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>
</flow>
```

**I am getting exception, but operation is there in WSDL**

```
Message               : No such operation: retrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. No such operation: retrieveServiceContent (java.lang.Exception)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:282 (null)
2. No such operation: retrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
java.lang.Exception: No such operation: retrieveServiceContent
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:282)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getMethodFromOperation(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:322)
    at org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.getMethod(CxfOutboundMessageProcessor.java:259)
    + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

Following is WSDL in operation: I am confused and around 4 days on it as i am new to mule.

```
  <operation name="RetrieveServiceContent">
     <input message="vim2:RetrieveServiceContentRequestMsg" />
     <output message="vim2:RetrieveServiceContentResponseMsg" />
     <fault name="RuntimeFault" message="vim2:RuntimeFaultFaultMsg"/>
  </operation>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this. I prefer to NOT us the way MuleStudio wants you to do it since I never really got that to work. Basically, whenever I create a webservice client my mule-config looks something like this:

```
<custom-transformer class="nl.thorax.someprogram.transformers.SomeRequestTransformer
<https:outbound-endpoint ref="someEndpoint" >
   <cxf:jaxws-client 
        clientClass="nl.thorax.someprogram.someclass"
        wsdlLocation="http://somedomain?wsdl
        port="somePort" 
        operation="someOperation"/>
</https:outbound-endpoint>
<custom-transformer class="nl.thorax.someprogram.transformers.SomeResponseTransformer
```

Where:

- SomeRequestTransformer: a transformer to create your request.
- someEndpoint: some endpoint defined in your MuleConfig. In my example, this is https but it could also be plain http.
- someclass: Important! This is your client class. It can be generated from a WSDL by free tools like Apache's WSDL2Java. Google is your friend on this.
- somePort: The port in your webservice to use. It can usually be found in the WSDL itself or in the client class you generated. The port more or less specifies what operations you can use.
- someOperation: The operation you want to use. Make sure it is typed EXACTLY the same as it's definition in the client class. Wrong use of cApItAlS will cause errors!
- SomeResponseTransformer: a transformer to do *something* with your response.

Now, the way I configure the call (and parse the response for that matter) is to use POJOs. My first transformer, the SomeRequestTransformer (based on the AbstractMessageTransformer in the Mule library) has a bit of code looking like this:

```
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException
{
  RequestObject request = new RequestObject();
  request.setText("Hello!");
  message.setPayload(request);
  return message;
}
```

I create the request, set the variables and return it to Mule. The RequestObject is a class generated by WSDL2Java and corresponds to some operation in the WSDL. Parsing the response works pretty much the same way.

Now I know from experience that a lot of webservices do not *quite* work in the same way. Try to implement my example yourself. If that doesn't work, please provide your Mule-Config and any and all Java classes you may be using.

**EDIT:**
I've created an example of my method that actually works. The files can be downloaded at [our website](http://www.thorax.nl/resources/example_project.zip). Please see the comments in the files. You have to manually create the Mule project, of course.

Points of note for the example:

- The XML-representation of the Mule-config can be found in the 'resources' folder in the archive.
- The 'nl.example.example' folder contains all the generated JAX-WS files.
- The WSDL location in Mule-config has to be changed since it contains an absolute path.
- The example creates an endpoint at `http://localhost:8088` for you to call. The flow contains a transformer which creates an example call using pre-defined parameters. Then it tries to connect to the webservice. I've used the default address used by SOAPUI when you create a mock service, but this could of course be changed into anything you want. The webservice (supposedly) returns something which is echoed into the user's browser.
- In this example, the parameters are actually Strings, since the WSDL-request doesn't contain anything. To figure out what object to pass to the cxf:jaxws-client look at the operation definition which can be found in the Port definition in your generated files.

Comment: Thank you for response Richard.

I am moving step by step now:

Actually i have a front screen with which i am able to connect to Mule using -> 

<http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:5678/httpHello" contentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" doc:name="HTTP">
        <http:body-to-parameter-map-transformer />
    </http:inbound-endpoint> ......

Now request is there inside and i recieved form parameters as : {txtBoxInstance:ServiceInstance1, txtBox2Instance:ServiceInstance2}

now i am writing transformer for that as you suggested

Comment: The transformer can be created in many different ways. My example used pure Java to create the request since that may be the easiest to actually understand to process. However, if you feel comfortable you can use any way you like to set the parameters. As long as the payload contains the request object when it gets to the https:outbound-endpoint you should be fine.

Comment: Fine, I am also using Java as i am new to Mule ESB and haven't used design base tools before so can't confuse myself. with WSDL2JAVA i have already generated stub and my request class name is -> ManagedObjectReference

I have used Java code before and in that the Operation is called as below -> vimPort.retrieveServiceContent(MG_OBJ_REF); . Here in Mule, i am facing "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Cannot load class 'ManagedObjectReference'", though everything is fine, I need to look why this exception is occurring

Comment: Somewht like ->
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating bean with name 'prjvmwareFlow1': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [esxiclient.CreateRequest] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [1]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.lang.Class' for property 'returnClass'

Comment: Richard, 
I have done above steps and in third step and now i performed step 3 and i am getting exception ---> 

Message               : No such operation: RetrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference
Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2

Comment: In continuation to above comment, i have used ---> 

<cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="VimService" wsdlLocation="C:/Users/his/MuleStudio/workspace/prjvmware/bin/service/vim/vimService.wsdl operation="RetrieveServiceContent" clientClass="com.esxclient.VimService" port="VimPort">
           
         </cxf:jaxws-client>

Comment: also includes ---> 
Exception stack is:
1. No such operation: RetrieveServiceContent (java.lang.Exception)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:282 (null)
2. No such operation: RetrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)

Comment: Might be trivial, but my WSDL2Java always generates operations with a small letter. Just to rule it out: could you change your operation into retrieveServiceContent (so 'small' r)?

Comment: Richard, It is same exception. I have checked port class and i found -> @WebResult(name = "returnval", targetNamespace = "urn:vim2") @RequestWrapper(localName = "RetrieveServiceContent", targetNamespace = "urn:vim2", className = "com.esxclient.RetrieveServiceContent") @WebMethod(operationName = "RetrieveServiceContent") @ResponseWrapper(localName = "RetrieveServiceContentResponse", targetNamespace = "urn:vim2", className = "com.esxclient.RetrieveServiceContentResponse") ->

Comment: Continued:

public com.esxclient.ServiceContent retrieveServiceContent( @WebParam(name = "_this", targetNamespace = "urn:vim2")
        com.esxclient.ManagedObjectReference _this
    ) throws RuntimeFaultFaultMsg;
--> FLOW -->
<http:outbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8080/as">
<cxf:jaxws-client 
doc:name="VimService"
wsdlLocation="C:/Users/his/MuleStudio/workspace/prjvmware/bin/service/vim/vimService.wsdl"
operation="retrieveServiceContent"  
clientClass="com.esxclient.VimService"
port="VimPort" enableMuleSoapHeaders="false" >
</cxf:jaxws-client>
</http:outbound-endpoint>

Comment: EXCEPTION -> Message : No such operation: retrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference
Code: MULE_ERROR--2

Comment: Exception stack is:
1. No such operation: retrieveServiceContent (java.lang.Exception)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:282 (null)
2. No such operation: retrieveServiceContent. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: ManagedObjectReference (org.mule.api.transport.DispatchException)
  org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor:150 (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transport/DispatchException.html)

Comment: Could you somehow provide me with the WSDL you are using? I'll try to create a demo for you to work with.

Comment: Hi Richard, Thank you for that. Following is content of WSDL in use ---> <definitions targetNamespace="urn:vim2Service"
   xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
   xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
   xmlns:interface="urn:vim2"
>
   <import location="vim.wsdl" namespace="urn:vim2" />
   <service name="VimService">
      <port binding="interface:VimBinding" name="VimPort">
         <soap:address location="https://112.120.20.26/sdk/vimService" />
      </port>
   </service>
</definitions>

Comment: In continuation to above comment following is operation defined in Import WSDL -> 
<operation name="RetrieveServiceContent">
         <input message="vim2:RetrieveServiceContentRequestMsg" />
         <output message="vim2:RetrieveServiceContentResponseMsg" />
         <fault name="RuntimeFault" message="vim2:RuntimeFaultFaultMsg"/>
      </operation>

Comment: Also, Service Class have -> @WebEndpoint(name = "VimPort")
    public VimPortType getVimPort() {
        return super.getPort(VimPort, VimPortType.class);
    } ..... AND ..... VimPortType have ----> @WebEndpoint(name = "VimPort")
    public VimPortType getVimPort() {
        return super.getPort(VimPort, VimPortType.class);
    }

Comment: Hi Richard, Update is that i have given TargetNamespace and Namespace the same and and flow moves forward. Now getting some -> Interceptor for {urn:vim2}VimService#{urn:vim2}RetrieveServiceContent has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <!--Arbortext, Inc., 1988-2008, v.4002-->
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html lang="en">
<!--
DO NOT ALTER OR REMOVE COPYRIGHT NOTICES OR THIS HEADER.

Comment: Also need to parse: org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$1 . If i remove the outbound-enpoint from logic and directly call Client.

Comment: Alright. I am currently working on fixing you up an example based on your input. I'll get back to you.

Comment: Richard, Could you please explain purpose of <https:outbound-endpoint ref="someEndpoint" >, is it mandatory to use and if yes then how to use the same like --> <outbound-endpoint address="https://122.120.20.26/sdk/vimService" doc:name="Generic" exchange-pattern="request-response"/> 

What attributes it should contain and what purpose it will solve in relation to web service call?

Comment: I've added an example to the answer. Please see the answer itself for more details.

Comment: Thank you richard that help a lot in understanding concept. I have seen when i call web service it should return RetrieveServiceContent Response object but getting following any idea -> 
WARN  2014-01-13 20:39:46,746 [[prjvmware].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain: Interceptor for {urn:vim2}VimService#{urn:vim2}RetrieveServiceContent has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Failed to route event via endpoint: DefaultOutboundEndpoint{endpointUri=http://localhost:8088/mockexampleSOAP, connector=HttpConnector
{

Comment: I am able to call web service but getting above exception in below settings:

<http:outbound-endpoint ref="WebserviceEndpoint" exchange-pattern="request-response" method="POST" doc:name="HTTP" > <cxf:jaxws-client doc:name="VimService"
  wsdlLocation="C:/Users/rasta/MuleStudio/workspace/prjvmware/bin/service/vim/vimService.wsdl"              operation="RetrieveServiceContent" clientClass="com.esxclient.VimService"
         port="VimPort" >
 </cxf:jaxws-client>
        </http:outbound-endpoint>
        
  <logger message="Received HTTP Response #[payload]" level="INFO"  doc:name="Logger" />

Comment: If i remove outbound Endpoint i think it should return me result in Payload in logger but then too it says -> ERROR 2014-01-13 23:26:32,074 [[prjvmware].connector.http.mule.default.receiver.02] org.mule.exception.DefaultMessagingExceptionStrategy: 
********************************************************************************
Message    : Unexpected wrapper element {urn:vim2}RetrieveServiceContent found.   Expected {urn:vim2}RetrieveServiceContentResponse.. Failed to route event via endpoint: org.mule.module.cxf.CxfOutboundMessageProcessor. Message payload is of type: PushbackInputStream

Comment: To be honest, I'm not quite sure what that means. It could be that your classes do not correspond to the WSDL you are using (don't know why). From what I can understand from your exceptions, the object returend by the JAX-WS client does not match the expected object based on your classes.